# In mapbasic,how to register a table in xlsx,not in xls?

Tags: mapbasic

I have tow files that only differ in  extention name, one xls ,the other xlsx.both contained the same things,same structure.there's no problem when I registered a table in xls,but when in xlsx,an error occured.

[image]

code list:

Include "mapbasic.def"
Include "menu.def"
Include "icons.def"

Declare Sub main
Declare Sub Combine

Sub main
   Register Table "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\desktop\test\fdd.xlsx"
   TYPE xls

End Sub

Comment: Short-time solution: save the .xlsx-document as .xls instead.

Comment: which version of MapInfo and Office you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Register Table "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\desktop\test\fdd.xlsx" TYPE XLS Range "Sheet1" Interactive Into ... + ".TAB"

Maybe you have to translate "Sheet1" into the language version of your Excel.

For Example --> in German you should change it to "Tabelle1"